# Trying to prepend a <h2> before the first-child element of a set of sub elements

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="expertise-list">
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I simply want to include a header before the first div, within each li. For example:

```
<ul class="expertise-list">
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <h2>Case title</h2>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <h2>Case title</h2>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <h2>Case title</h2>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
    <div>Case title</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried experimenting with the following jquery, but I have only managed to get a title to appear on the first list item:

```
$('.expertise-list li div:first-child').before('<h2>Cases</h2>');
```

I'm sure this is something really simple to achieve! Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is because the divs are not the `first-child` of the li.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code p is the first-child but not divs. So you can use [first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

```
$('.expertise-list li div:first-of-type').before('<h2>Cases</h2>');
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes absolute sense - thanks for the speedy reply! This seems like the best solution - although other answers do work - this works in the most sensible way!

Answer (score 2):

You can just append after `<p>`

```
$('.expertise-list li p').after('<h2>Cases</h2>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can use `.after()` for `p` tag in `li`

```
$('.expertise-list li p').after('<h2>Cases</h2>');
```